# Own Set whih inherited from List<int>

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I want create class `Set` which inherited from `List<int>`

```
class Set : List<int>
{
  public void Add(tmp)
  public void Pop(tmp)
  public print()
}
```

But I have problem how should look consturctor could someone give me example?
I know how should looks methods(I will write them myself).

Comment: Collection called "Set" should not have `Pop` method. `Pop` sounds like a part of `Stack` / `Queue` functionality.

Comment: `List<T>` already has a method called `Add(T item)`. You might need to use the `new` keyword if it has the same syntax as the `List<T>.Add(T)` method.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` has a parameterless constructor, so you don't *need* to do anything within your constructor.

You can even omit it altogether if you don't plan on adding constructors with parameters, it'll automatically run the empty  constructor on the base class when you create a `new Set()`:

```
class Set : List<int>
{
    public new void Add(int tmp)
    {
        // custom logic here
        base.Add(tmp);
    }
}

Set myset = new Set();
myset.Add(43);
```

Note that you chose to *inherit* from `List<int>`, which means that all members defined by `List<int>` are also available on your `Set` class. An alternative solution is to *wrap* the list:

```
class Set : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private readonly List<int> wrappedCollection = new List<int>();

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        wrappedCollection.Add(value);
    }

    ...
}
```

This way you can choose which interfaces you want to implement, and add additional functionality like your `print()` method.

Comment: So how in my method can I reference to Set?

Comment: From within a method, you can reference the `Set` as `this`, and you can call `base.Add()` to add something to the collection. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Smth like this new bas = new Set1();  bas.Add(2); ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, see the first code snippet on how you could instantiate and use your `Set`.

Comment: One more why i can't put it in main? Set myset = new Set();

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Within the class type `ctor` then hit tab twice, this will create the default constructor:

```
        public Set()
        {

        }
```

Using Set as a class name could be confusing though as the 'set' keyword is used in properties

Comment: Are you aware of any case where type name can be used in place of `set` keyword? Set is a well defined mathematical concept and its (mis)naming should not be determined by language syntax unless it would cause real issues.

Comment: This is in the context of the original poster not knowing how to create a constructor

Answer (score 0):

An alternative possibility is the use of extension methods as it seems to me you are only trying to add functionality to List by way of methods. Here is an example:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an empty Dropdown Option at the start of the list
    /// If the list is null then null will be returned and nothing happens
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">
    /// List of dropdown options
    /// </param>
    /// <returns >The list of dropdown options with the prepended empty option</returns>
    public static IList<SelectListItem> AddEmpty(this IList<SelectListItem> list)
    {
        list?.Insert(0, new SelectListItem {Value = string.Empty, Text = Resources.Labels.ChooseListItem});

        return list;
    }
}
```